# How to plot $arg(\frac{z-a}{z-b})=\theta$ using intuition? How to find its Cartesian equation?

Tags: complex-numbers

> How to plot $arg(\frac{z-a}{z-b})=\theta$ using intuition? How to find
>   its Cartesian equation?

z is a complex number.

Answer (score 3):

Given the fixed points $a$ and $b$, and $z$ is a variable point. The angle $AZB$ is a constant angle $\theta$ means that $z$ moves on a **part circle** due to theorem "angles in the same segment are equal".

This is quite easily seen by drawing a picture and noting that $$arg\left(\frac{z-a}{z-b}\right)=arg(z-a)-arg(z-b)$$

To find the Cartesian equation, write out in component form the fraction $\left(\frac{z-a}{z-b}\right)=\omega$ and multiply top and bottom by the conjugate of the bottom so that you can identify the real and imaginary parts.

Then apply the relevant conditions on this number having an argument of $\theta$. For example, if $\theta=\frac {\pi}{4}$, the conditions would be
$$Re(\omega)=Im(\omega)$$
This would give the equation of the circle.
But also we require, in this example, both $Re(\omega)>0$ and $Im(\omega)>0$, and it is these inequalities which determine which part of the circle is relevant.

Comment: An example would be more helpful :-/

Comment: Find an example for yourself and try it out. If you get stuck, pose a new question. ;)