# Find the Cartesian equation of the locus described by $\arg \left(\frac{z-2}{z+5} \right)= \frac{\pi}{4}$

Tags: complex-numbers

My working:

$$ \frac{x + iy - 2}{x + iy + 5} $$
$$ \frac{(x - 2 + iy)(x+5-iy)}{(x + 5 + iy)(x+5-iy)} $$
$$ \frac{x^2+5x-ixy-2x-10+2iy+ixy+5iy+y^2}{x^2+5x-ixy+5x+25-5iy+ixy+5iy+y^2} $$
$$ \frac{x^2+3x-10+y^2+7iy}{x^2+10x+25+y^2}$$
$$ \frac {\Im(z)}{\Re(z)} = \tan \frac{\pi}{4} = 1$$
$$ x^2 + 3x + y^2 - 10 = 7y $$
$$ x^2 + 3x + y^2 - 7y = 10 $$
$$ \left(x+ \frac 32\right)^2 + \left(y- \frac 72\right)^2 = 10 + \frac 94 + \frac {49}{4} $$
$$ \left(x- -\frac 32\right)^2 + \left(y- \frac 72\right)^2 = \left(\frac {7 \sqrt{2}}{2}\right)^2 $$

Is this correct? Is there a better method than what I did here?

Comment: I would say that's about the official way to do it, disregarding some shortcuts.

Comment: Here's another related question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1392047/how-to-plot-arg-fracz-az-b-theta-using-intuition-how-to-find-its-carte

Answer (score 3):

Let me try this way -

The numerator is the line joining $Z(x,y)$ to $(2,0)$ while the denominator joins $Z(x,y)$ to $(-5,0)$ .

Geometrically, These two points are at a $45^\circ$ angle to each other.

Both the points *should* be on the locus. (Imagine a very small line at each point making $45^\circ$ angle with the other line)

Now, two points on the locus suspend an angle of $45^\circ$ to any other point on the locus implies - the locus is a circle!! *and* the center is at $90^\circ$ to these two line.

The center also lies on the perpendicular bisector of these two points, and so, the center is at $(-1.5,3.5)$. The two points are on the circle. So, radius is done too.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint for another method:**

Translate this problem into pure geometry: denote $A$ the point with affix $-5$, $B$ the point with affix $2$, $M$ the point with affix $z$. The  condition translates into $\angle AMB=\frac\pi4$.

Now use the *inscribed angle theorem*: the locus of $M$ is a circular arc. The centre $O$ of this arc  is such that $\angle AOB=\frac\pi2$. Hence $O$ is the intersection point of the upper semi-circle with diameter $[AB]$ and the perpendicular bisector of $[AB]$.

Comment: Well, I was a 4 seconds late, but I solved it completely, so I am not removing my answer.

Comment: The locus is only  an arc of the circle, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @WinVineeth : The fact that your answer is not the first one or not the only one is not a reason to delete it. $\qquad$

Comment: @WinVineeth: I agree with Michael Hardy.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Oh well, I thought we can't put the same answer, once someone already did that. Many a time, people deleted their posts because the same answer has already been given. This is to be discussed in meta, not here anyway.